# Are there standard dimensions for kayak holes used for wheeled carts?

Tags: kayaks

Regarding the type of kayak cart with pins that protrude through the kayak hull -- do you have to match the exact cart to model of kayak? (and, perhaps, brand).

Or is there a standard set of dimensions (pin diameter, length, and spacing)?

I suspect the answer may be "no" based on the expense of carts of this type. Product info I've looked at doesn't seem to include these measurements either.

Comment: Assuming this is related to your related [question here](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/24873/4079) notice that the width is adjustable on the cart for scupper holes in your image.