# What are the pros/cons of different types of kayak carts?

Tags: kayaks

I'm looking into kayak carts and noticed there are two basic types - ones which have pins that protrude through the hull using the scupper holes, and others which provide more of a base that the kayak sits on.

At first glance the pin type seems like it would be a better choice because of the positive connection to the hull, and maybe without requiring straps.

But I've never used either type of cart and wonder if there are other pros/cons of each design that should be considered?  For instance, the pin type might require elevating the hull a lot more than the other type.. etc.

Sit-on-top type:

[image]

Pin type:

[image]

(Assume for the sake of argument that your kayak has scupper holes so that either type of cart is an option).

Comment: Also see 'Problem three" in [this answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/9257/4079)

Comment: @JamesJenkins thanks, that's a good point. BTW, awesome post! :)  I actually happened to meet someone doing a long bike/kayak tour once but didn't take much note of her particular equipment (https://kickasstrips.com/2014/06/renata-chlumska-around-america-adventure-a-self-supported-kayak-bicycle-trip-around-the-periphery-of-the-usa/)

Answer (score 4):

There's a fairly short answer:

- The first type is suitable for all craft, including open canoes, sea kayaks and other general touring boats, playboats, in fact just about anything with a relatively wide flat hull.
- The second type is suitable for a fairly narrow range of "sit on top" craft that have suitable drain holes in the hull, though for those craft it will give a more positive engagement.

The latter may be the better purchase if you both have a suitable craft and you're intending to tow behind a bicycle. Though the former is more versatile if you're planning to upgrade in the future or try other types of paddlesports. If the trolley is just for hauling the boat from the car to the water, and you have a suitable craft for either, then it probably makes very little difference which you choose.